# Delay differential equations with pink noise

Tags: python, differential-equations, stochastic

I need to solve a set of delay differential equations and I want to use pink noise in these equations.

I tried doing it with the Pydelay package for Python, but the problem is that I need to either generate the noise and then pass it to the simulation or generate noise during the simulation. The first option doesn’t work because parameters specified in this solver need to be constant and noise changes over time. The second option doesn’t work because Pydelay only supports generating noise in which every sample is independent of others, which is not the case for pink noise.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Here's my code (I need I1 and I2 to be pink noises, not constant like in my code):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Aug  2 15:35:15 2016

@author: kasienka
"""
#!python
import pydelay
from time import time
import math
import numpy as np
from numpy import fft
from scipy import integrate
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import sys
import pylab as pl
from pydelay import dde23

# define the equations
eqns = {
    'y1' : 'I1 - y1(t-tau) + epsilon * pow(y2(t-tau), 1.1)',
    'y2' : 'I2 - y2(t-tau) + epsilon * pow(y1(t-tau), 1.1)'
    }
#define the parameters
params = {
    'I2' : 0.2,
    'I1' : 0.4,
    'tau': 1.31,
    'epsilon': 0.2
    }

# Initialise the solver
dde = dde23(eqns=eqns, params=params)

# set the simulation parameters
dde.set_sim_params(tfinal=50, dtmax=0.0001)

histdic = {
    'y1': lambda t: 0.2,
    'y2': lambda t: 0.4
    }
dde.hist_from_funcs(histdic, 1000)

# run the simulator
dde.run()
p1 = []
p2 = []
x1 = []
x2 = []
czasy = np.linspace(0, 50, 10000)
for el in times:
    x10 = dde.sol_spl(el)['y1']
    x20 = dde.sol_spl(el)['y2']
    prob1 = 1.0 / (1 + 3.14**(-(x10 - x20)) )
    prob2 = 1.0 / (1 + 3.14**(-(x20 - x10)) )
    p1.append(prob1)
    p2.append(prob2)
    x1.append(x10)
    x2.append(x20)
fig = pl.figure()
pl.plot(times, p1, label = '$p_1$')
pl.plot(times, p2, label = '$p_2$')
pl.xlabel('$time$')
pl.ylabel('$probabilities$')
pl.legend()
pl.savefig(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Do you think adding working code would help describe the problem?

Comment: So the problem is generating *pink noise*?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want dynamical noise¹. In that case, you should first realise that there are several types of differential equations with fundamentally different solvers:

- **Delay differential equations (DDEs)** are typically solved with either:

  - embedded, multi-step Runge-Kutta methods where the past is interpolated (this is what Pydelay does),
  - single-step integrators with the integration step dividing all delays.
- **Stochastic differential equations (SDEs)** are solved with simple single-step methods (all based on the Euler method). Multi-step methods are still a hot topic, and embedded methods have only been proposed very recently.

  All treatises on SDEs I am aware of (theoretical and methods; however they are not that many admittedly), consider only white noise (Wiener process); realising pink noise is a problem on its own. All I could find with a quick search was [a paper on simulating white noise with a white-noise SDE](//doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.81.031105).
- **Stochastic delay differential equations (SDDEs)** again need special solvers. I am not very familiar with them, but obviously you at least inherit all the limitations of DDEs and SDEs. Hence the best solver would be a single-step method with the integration step dividing all delays. Going by a quick glance at the literature, this is indeed what is done. Mind you that this does not address the problem of pink noise.

As already said, Pydelay uses a multi-step method with interpolation. This is not designed for and incapable of properly dealing with stochasticity (if it were, it would be a remarkable solver for SDEs already, i.e., without delay). Instead what it does is treating the multi-step method as a single-step method and adding noise afterwards. As the authors of Pydelay remark themselves, this “is quite crude”. Moreover, actually using pink noise (even with the crude method) would require you to reprogram the software and may result in inherent problems with the error estimator of the integrator. I strongly recommend against this. Even if you succeed, all the advantages of using an advanced DDE solver (e.g., adaptive steps) are lost anyway, so it’s easier to write a new, more simple integrator from scratch.

If you really need to do this, I recommend finding out how to solve SDEs with pink noise first and then extend the method to SDDEs (which hopefully is rather straightforward).

---

<sup>¹ If you want to have observational noise, that’s easy: Just add it to your solution.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is generating pink noise for all the elements in your dataset?

```
def voss(nrows, ncols=16):
    """Generates pink noise using the Voss-McCartney algorithm.

    nrows: number of values to generate
    rcols: number of random sources to add

    returns: NumPy array
    """
    array = np.empty((nrows, ncols))
    array.fill(np.nan)
    array[0, :] = np.random.random(ncols)
    array[:, 0] = np.random.random(nrows)

    # the total number of changes is nrows
    n = nrows
    cols = np.random.geometric(0.5, n)
    cols[cols >= ncols] = 0
    rows = np.random.randint(nrows, size=n)
    array[rows, cols] = np.random.random(n)

    df = pd.DataFrame(array)
    df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=0, inplace=True)
    total = df.sum(axis=1)

    return total.values
```

Source: [ThinkDSP](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP/blob/master/code/voss.ipynb)